# Pytorch - Object of type 'method' has no len()

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, lstm, pytorch-lightning

So I'm trying to train a time series model using pytorch lightning library.

But after running the following code,

```
trainer = pl.Trainer(
    max_epochs = N_EPOCHS,
)

trainer.fit(model,data_module)
```

I'm getting this error,

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/sampler.py in __iter__(self)
     64 
     65     def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[int]:
---> 66         return iter(range(len(self.data_source)))
     67 
     68     def __len__(self) -> int:

TypeError: object of type 'method' has no len()
```

[image]

Also here's my data module initialization,

```
data_module = StockPriceDataModule(train_sequences, test_sequences, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
data_module.setup()
```

DataModule class

```
class StockPriceDataModule(pl.LightningDataModule):
    def __init__(self, train_sequences, test_sequences, batch_size = 8):
        super().__init__()
        self.train_sequences = train_sequences
        self.test_sequences = test_sequences
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        
    def setup(self, stage=None):
        self.train_dataset = StockDataset(self.train_sequences)
        self.test_dataset = StockDataset(self.test_sequences)
        
    def train_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(
            self.train_dataset,
            batch_size = self.batch_size,
            shuffle = False,
            num_workers = 2
        )

    def val_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(
            self.test_dataloader,
            batch_size=1,
            shuffle = False,
            num_workers=1,
        )
    
    def test_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(
            self.test_dataloader,
            batch_size=1,
            shuffle = False,
            num_workers=1,
        )
```

Im kinda beginner. So I was just following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ODEGJ_kh2aA to learn about time series forecasting with multiple features using LSTM. My code is almost same...

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Might be wrong here but you just need to create a method inside of your data loader class. Something like def **len**(self): return len(dataloader).

[custom data loaders in Pytorch](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/custom_dataset_transforms_loader.html)